# How change name client file socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I use `node.js + socket.io` in project.
There is a two node.js scripts on server.

> web.com:8181/socket.io/socket.io.js
>   web.com:3030/socket.io/socket.io.js

How I can change `socket.io` name on any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but if what you're asking is how you can change:

```
web.com:8181/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

to anything like these:

```
web.com:8181/somethingelse/socket.io.js
web.com:8181/yourown.js
```

Then, there's an easy way and a hard way.  The easy way, is to just make a copy of the file, put it in your own place on your server with whatever name and path you want and create a static route to that file.

The harder way is to modify the socket.io server code to change the custom route it registers in your node server so that it can respond to a request for a different path and filename to server the built-in socket.io.js file.